# DatePicker default value

Tags: android, datepicker

I would like to change the default value of DatePicker programatically, but it seems there is no DatePicker.setMonth\Year\DayOfMonth function or something similar...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

The method is :

```
public void updateDate (int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth)
```

Have a look at : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DatePickerDialog.html